# ROS Answers SE migration: Loggers in ROS

Tags: ros, rosout, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to understand loggers in ROS. The [roscpp overview page](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging) mentions different loggers. And when you use the `NAMED` macros, they make "child" loggers. It also mentions there is more information in a configuration file that is not linked.

What is a logger? And what is a child logger and the need/use case for it?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276443/loggers-in-ros/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Logger allows programmer to control the verbosity of the print statements, with change of verbosity level in configuration file, obviously without recompiling the code. As you have read in the [Overview page](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging), ROS logger support different versions. By changing the [verbosity level](http://wiki.ros.org/Verbosity%20Levels) in the [configuration file](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration), one can control what will get printed on the system console. Please read section 2 of [rosconsole](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole) page for further details. Also rqt_console, allow much better control over print statements and display of them.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2017-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1